# MKMapView: show or hide an array of annotations without looping

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsarray, mkmapview, mkannotation

I have an array of annotations.

```
    NSArray *annotations = [mapView annotations];
```

I can show or hide them by looping through the array.

```
    for (i=0; i<[annotations count]; i++)
    {
        annotation = (AddressAnnotation*)[annotations objectAtIndex:i];
        [[mapView viewForAnnotation:annotation] setHidden:YES];
    }
```

But is there any way to do that without looping?

We can add annotations by the method

```
- (void)addAnnotations:(NSArray *)annotations;
```

Also we can remove the annotations by like below:

```
- (void)removeAnnotations:(NSArray *)annotations;
```

But i cant find out any method to show or hide an array of annotations :(

Comment: Why do you need to do it without looping? It seems that looping does what you want in this case?

Comment: because i want to save time on showing or hiding of annotations & i have about 3000 annotations

Comment: 'Looping' is unavoidable.  Even if there is an API to hide an array of annotations, you'll still have to _iterate_ over the whole collection.

Answer (score 1):

not sure if you solved this, but in MapKit you can use

```
NSArray *annotationsOnMap = mapView.annotations;
if ([annotationsOnMap count] > 0) {
 [mapView removeAnnotations:annotationsOnMap];
}
```